# Sum of multiples below 10,000

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Estoy con una duda que no sé como resolver.

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Si enumeramos todos los números naturales por debajo de 10 que son múltiplos de 3, 5 o 7, obtenemos 3, 5, 6, 7 y 9. La suma de estos múltiplos es 30. Calcula la suma de todos los múltiplos de 3 , 5 o 7 por debajo de 10000.

Esta pregunta se formula en un formulario que comprueba si la respuesta es correcta.

He desarrollado el código y lo he comprobado varias veces, el problema es que cuando pongo el resultado en el formulario me dice que está mal.

Este es mi código:

```
function sumMultiplos() {
  const reducer = (a, b) => a + b;
  const multiplos = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
    const numeros = [3, 5, 7];
    numeros.map(numero => {
      if (i % numero === 0) {
        multiplos.push(i);
      }
    })
  }
  return multiplos.reduce(reducer, 0);
};
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO **en español**. Por favor edita la pregunta para traducirla y, de paso, coloca el código como texto. Revisa [Cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: El problema que veo es que si un número candidato es múltiplo de varios de los números de tu lista, lo metes varias veces a `multiplos`, por ejemplo, 21 es múltiplo de 3 y de 7, y lo colocas dos veces en el resultado.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón !!!!!!!

Comment: Proyecto euler verdad?

Comment: Una empresa random

Answer (score -2):

Gracias a la respuesta de jachguate, el problema se resuelve tan fácil como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

```
function sumMultiplos() {
  const reducer = (a, b) => a + b;
  const multiplos = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
    const numeros = [3, 5, 7];
    numeros.map(numero => {
      if (i % numero === 0) {
        multiplos.push(i);
      }
    })
  }
  const uniqueValues = [...new Set(multiplos)];
  return uniqueValues.reduce(reducer, 0);
};
```